# How to remove specif rows from a dataset based on a list

Tags: r, list, subset

I wish to select everything from my dataset except the ID that are into `ID_to_drop`
I've already manage to select these specific rows but I was not able to exclude then.
Here is a example:

```
c("AKBV0100000.1", "AKBV0100000.1", "AKVX0100000.1", "AKVX0100000.1", "AP019675.1","AP019675.1","NZ_CADIHK000000000.1", "NZ_CADIHK000000000.1", NZ_CADIHI000000000.1","NZ_CADIHI000000000.1") %>%  
as.tibble() %>% 
mutate(x = runif(10))

ID_to_drop<- c("NZ_CADIHI000000000.1","NZ_CADIHJ000000000.1","NZ_CADIHK000000000.1") 

ALL_IDs %>% subset(value %in% ID_to_drop)
```

This script returns

```
  value                     x
  <chr>                 <dbl>
1 NZ_CADIHK000000000.1 0.644 
2 NZ_CADIHK000000000.1 0.396 
3 NZ_CADIHI000000000.1 0.0870
4 NZ_CADIHI000000000.1 0.924
```

But these rows are the exactly the ones that I want to exclude

I'll be glad if somebody help me :)

Comment: Try `ALL_IDs %>% subset(!value %in% ID_to_drop)`

Comment: Perfect man! Solved!